# carousel animations effects in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, animation, carousel

Is there any other default animation can we add in Bootstrap carousel other that slide. In `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">`
I don't want the sliding effect is there any other effect we can add without writing any extra code or animation effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use fade effect other than slide effect, try this :

CSS:

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade col-lg-8 col-offset-2">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="//placehold.it/1300x500" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
           <div class="item">
             <img src="//placehold.it/1300x500/55EE55" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
           <div class="item">
             <img src="//placehold.it/1300x500/CCFEFE" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
</div>
```

Check out these : [Example1](http://www.bootply.com/86170) and [Example2](http://www.bootply.com/64693)

Comment: Dont know how else wanders here after 7 years, but here we go. I would extend the css with this line: `.carousel-fade>.carousel-inner> :not(.active) {opacity: 0; display: block !important;}` This eliminates the weird instant disappearing and waits for a smooth opacity to 0 effect